# CSS Media Queries Called 200px Later?

Tags: html, css

I noticed a serious issue in Chrome today with my sites. My media queries are being called ~260px over where they are set to trigger! It is happening on multiple sites and my layouts are thrown off.

If I have `@media screen and (min-width: 1000px)` it is called in chrome at 1260px instead... These are screen widths the browser is telling me in developer mode.

I'm stumped and all my old sites are screwed up in chrome now... anyone else having this issue with the new version of chrome?

Comment: do you have code we can look at... just in case? perhaps a fiddle?

Comment: can you show a live link

Comment: @floor [link](http://www.cardboardsword.net) My site has a lot of media queries and looked fine until I updated Chrome

Comment: I don't see any serious issues on the page. Are you sure you're not zoomed out?

Comment: @MrLister good call. Chrome was zoomed in to 125% and would not return to 100% size no matter what I did. Re-installed and now it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome was stuck on one zoom level somehow, and it was more than 100% so it looked like the media queries were happening at the wrong places. Some error in updating, I re-installed and zoom works again.